# Parse HTML Content using PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

I need to get "Lorem Ipsum" from below html code using php, i have main div with "data-porid", now how can i get my require data.

```
<div class="row" data-porid="XXXXXX">
                <div class="label">Creditor Name
                    <span class="moreInfo" ck-icon="info" data-placement="top" data-content="The name of the company that owns or services this account."></span>
                </div>
                <div class="detail">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is using JavaScript out of the question? I can't see `data="Lorem Ipsum"`?

Comment: Use htmldomparser

Comment: i need "Lorem Ipsum" as a output. 
also i used ,
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        $query = "//div[@data-porid='XXXXXX']";

but dont know what todo next.